# Android studio, open a file , continuously write and then close

Tags: java, android, file, io, fileoutputstream

I have code that is generating data every second and displaying onscreen. 
This all works fine but I want to create a log file of all the data to analyze later.

I can open/write/close a file each time data is created but I am unsure of how much processing power this is using as it is continually opening and closing the file

```
  String data= reading1","+reading2+","+time +"/n";
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("data.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            out.write(data.getBytes());
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

I would prefer to have the file open when the start button is clicked.

```
if ( v.getId() == R.id.start ){
                // checks which button is clicked
                Log.d("dennis", "Scan working"); //logs the text
                // open a file
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("data.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

but when it comes to closing the file, no options for .close() appear when ***out*** is typed

```
if ( v.getId() == R.id.stop ){
                // checks which button is clicked

                out. // no valid options appear
                messageValue.setText(R.string.stopButtonText);// changes the hallo world text
                readNoRead=false;

            }
```

Does all the open/write/close need to be together or is it possible to

```
***open file***
-----
Cycle through all the data
-----
***Close file***
```

Comment: You can close the output stream whenever you want, wherever you want, so long as you have a reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store a link to your `FileOutputStream` on top level in your class.

Example to your code:

```
FileOutputStream out;

void clickStart() {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.start){
        // checks which button is clicked
        Log.d("dennis", "Scan working"); //logs the text
        // open a file
        try {
            out = openFileOutput("data.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

void writeData() {
    String data= reading1+","+reading2+","+time +"/n";
    try {
        out.write(data.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void clickStop() {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.stop) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        messageValue.setText(R.string.stopButtonText);// changes the hello world text
            readNoRead=false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this information. I have the open and close file up and running. I am just completing the writing part on another activity and it should be working perfectly shortly.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to open, process and close a file all in one block without closing the file.

Your `out` variable is not showing any method suggestions because it has not been defined in that block. Change the line

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("data.csv", CONTEXT.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
out = openFileOutput("data.csv", CONTEXT.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and then add `FileOutputStream out;` to a line above the first `if` statement (outside of the block).

You may want to also look into 'try-catch-finally', or 'try with resources' as options for closing files in a try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks so much for this information. This solution has made it much clearer to me